# How do I use JSON in older browsers?

Tags: javascript, json

In javascript, I want to use `JSON.stringify`. But some (older) browsers do not recognize `JSON` as a defined object. Is there a javascript file that I can include that defines JSON, and all it's awesome functionality, for browsers that do not natively support `JSON`?

I should note that I'm referring to a specifically defined `JSON` object, rather than the more general concept of javascript object notation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Douglas Crockford (the inventor of JSON) provides [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), an efficient JSON "parser" that doesn't actually parse JSON; it uses regular expressions to sanitise JSON before passing it to eval, and falls back on native JSON support if the browser has it.

He also provides a more conventional recursive-descent parser and a state-machine-based parser in the same repo.